# replace if else to switch case

Tags: javascript

How can I replace these conditions from if-else to switch case:

```
  const getClassName = (flow, side, type) => {
    if (flow === 'Lateral' && side === 'right' && type === 'type 1') {
      return classes.LateralRightFirstType;
    } else if (flow === 'Lateral' && side === 'left' && type === 'type 1') {
      return classes.LateralLeftFirstType;
    } else if (flow === 'Lateral' && side === 'right' && type === 'type 2') {
      return classes.LateralRightSecondType;
    } else if (flow === 'Lateral' && side === 'left' && type === 'type 2') {
      return classes.LateralLeftSecondType;
    }
  };
```

Comment: What's wrong with `if..else` and why do you think a `switch` would be better?

Comment: @deceze, the flow will grow. I thought it would be better to make a switch-case

Comment: That would still require you to add one line per case, which doesn't fundamentally improve anything. There have been some alternative suggestions how to approach it below, including the comments to the answers…

Answer (score 0):

The best solution will be to create a `dict` and get the value. It is easier to read and maintain

To get valur for

```
getClassNameWithSwitch("Lateral", "left", "type 1");
```

you just have to do

```
function getClassNameWithSwitch(flow, side, type) {
  const dict = {
    Lateral: {
      right: {
        "type 1": classes.LateralRightFirstType,
        "type 2": classes.LateralRightSecondType,
      },
      left: {
        "type 1": classes.LateralLeftFirstType,
        "type 2": classes.LateralLeftSecondType,
      },
    },
  };

 return dict[flow][side][type];
}
```

Comment: Indeed this solution doesn't replace from `if-else` to `switch`. But we all know that that solution will either be hard to implement or very hard to maintain. This solution is easy to read and maintain.

Comment: @bravo, the answer to the question "How do I make my code harder to understand" isn't to write code that's harder to understand. The answer is "Perhaps your code is ok".

Answer (score -1):

Since `switch` requires a single comparable value to switch on, this would be the only really sensible way to apply a `switch` here:

```
switch (`${flow}|${side}|${type}`) {
    case 'Lateral|right|type 1':
        return ...;
    case '...':
        ...
}
```

But if you're going that way, an object would make even more sense:

```
const choices = {
    'Lateral|right|type 1': classes.LateralRightFirstType,
    ...
}

return choices[`${flow}|${side}|${type}`];
```

Or:

```
const choices = {
    Lateral: {
        right: {
            'type 1': classes.LateralRightFirstType
            ...
        }
    }
}

return choices[flow][side][type];
```

Comment: In this case switch-case is totally pointless, you can directly generate class from it, instead of doing such pseudo class generating.

Your entire code might be replaced with: `const className = ${flow}-${side}-${type}`

Comment: `'type 1'` doesn't translate to `FirstType` that magically. Depending on where those values come from, this form of normalisation may be necessary. But yes, if it could be done this directly, that'd be even better. My latter two approaches somewhat hint in this direction, but only OP can make that realisation.